# RSelenium Chrome Up

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium, rselenium

Having problem with the codes below

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome')
remDr$open()
```

Codes open a chrome browser with a pop up saying "Disable developer mode extensions". Would like to now how to disable popup using R

[image]